# Why doesn't my app's theme get updated in my main activity anymore?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I'm having a problem where my main activity's theme will not update in Android Studio.
I set my theme in styles.xml to `android:Theme.Light`, checked my main activity and saw it updated. I then changed my theme to `android:Theme.Holo.Light` but my main activity didn't update this time.
If I run the app on my device it looks how it should, so it's only Android Studio that's the problem.
I've tried to Sync Project with Gradle Files, but that didn't work (all files are in their default directories).
Is my only option to remake the app from scratch?

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
...
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean and build the project again?

Comment: @MarkKorzhov I just tried that and it didn't work. The Preview still shows the Light theme instead of Holo.Light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking around the GUI some more, I facepalmed when I found there's a refresh button for the Preview window which, when clicked, updated and displayed the correct theme.
I'm not proud of finding this either, if anything I'm ashamed I didn't think of this sooner.